# can't instantiate same class multiple times

Tags: php, oop

**Really, really sorry.. it seems the problem was with the KLogger I used. I remove KLogger from my code and now it works perfectly well. Never thought a simple logger class would cause the problem.**

here's my php class

```
<?php
session_start(); 

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(1);

class Gamification {

    private $webAction;
    private $currentLimit;
    private $maxLimit;

    function __construct($getWebAction) {           
        $this->webAction = $getWebAction;

        include ("config.path.php");
        include ($config['BASE_DIR']."/include/KLogger.php");
        $log = KLogger::instance($config['BASE_DIR'].'/log/');

        $log->logInfo('class.gamification.php: line 21: webAction:'.$getWebAction);

    }

    public function getMaxLimit(){
        $this->maxLimit = 99;
        return $this->maxLimit;
    }

    public function getCurrentLimit(){
        $this->currentLimit = 3;
        return $this->currentLimit;
    }
}

?>
```

and i tried to instantiate it multiple times from other php page, like this:

```
 $gamification = new Gamification("expensesCategory");
    $currentLimit = $gamification->getCurrentLimit();
    $maxLimit = $gamification->getMaxLimit();

    $gamificationInfoExpFixedMonthly = new Gamification("expensesFixedMonthly");
    $currentLimitExpFixedMonthly = $gamificationInfoExpFixedMonthly->getCurrentLimit();
    $maxLimitExpFixedMonthly = $gamificationInfoExpFixedMonthly->getMaxLimit();
```

but the problem is the 2nd Gamification class (`$gamificationInfoExpFixedMonthly`) won't ever be reached/initialized... no error would be returned, it's just won't reach there.. all html codes below that line also wouldn't appear...am I doing anything wrong? anyway I'll try to update my php and give the result later

Comment: What to you get if you dump (var_dump()) $gamificationDeduct ?

Comment: I think your problem is just a space left `$gamificationSearch ->getCurrentLimit($currentUserName);` try `$gamificationSearch->getCurrentLimit($currentUserName);` a space befor the `->`

Comment: @Babblo I'll get nothing if i var_dump $gamificationDeduct.. seems like  it can't even reach there.. because I put logfile everytime the class is instantiated.. but the 2nd time the class isn't even instantiated

Comment: @JorgeCampos i don't think that's the problem, because if I comment out the first gamification class, the $gamificationDeduct just works perfectly. furthermore in my actual codes there's no space there

Comment: Why is `$belongsTo` in the constructor and `getCurrentLimit()` if it's never used? Also, `$currentLimit` is not defined in `getCurrentLimit()`

Comment: Have you configured your server to show all errors? php.ini E_ALL

Comment: I agree with @JorgeCampos, you have errors but just aren't seeing them. Set `display_error = On` and `error_reporting = E_ALL` in your `php.ini` file and restart your web server

Comment: If `KLogger.php` includes a class then you're trying to redefine that class with your second instantiation because you include it in the constructor. If you move the include statement outside the class everything should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems in your class... Let see:

First in your constructor you are passing a variable that is never used:

```
function __construct($belongsTo, $getWebAction) {
                  //       ^this one here what is is doing here???
```

Second You create a method that use a local variable that was not defined

```
public function getCurrentLimit($belongsTo) {
    return $currentLimit;
                //^here it should be: $this->currentLimit
}
```

Also you have to define it on your class in order to use on your method

```
 //.... some more stuff
private $initialLimit = 3;
private $maxLimit = 10;
private $currentLimit = 0;
```

And more:

```
public function getCurrentLimit($belongsTo) {
                                 // ^ this is not used at all
    return $currentLimit;
                //^here it should be: $this->currentLimit
}
```

Fix all that and it should work

Comment: actually my code above was simplified from the actual code.. $belongsTo was actually being used. anyway however, I've stripped the class' code to bare minimum.. but the problem still persists. i've edited the code above which reflects the full codes that i'm using now